# C++ iostream operator overladed function return type

Tags: c++, return, operator-overloading, iostream

I'm still in learning phase of basic formats and commands of C++.
I'm now at class operator function overloading and came to `<<` and `>>`. My question is: when they are defined in friend functions such as below:

```
ostream &operator << ( ostream &output, const PhoneNumber &number )
```

and are called with PhoneNumber class `phone` like this:

```
cout << phone << endl;
```

Why is the friend function returning `ostream&`? I mean when a function returns a value of a particular type, it is generally received by a fundamental type variable such as bool, int, char, string, and etc. However, for `ostream` and `istream`, the returned type of `ostream&` is not being saved. Then, in this case, shouldn't it be void (carry out the task and terminate without returning any values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the friend function returning ostream&?

To allow operators to be chained together.  The operators return a reference to the same stream that was passed in.  Without that return reference, you would not be able to call `<< endl` on the return value of `cout << phone`.

> I mean when a function returns a value of a particular type, it is generally received by a fundamental type variable such as bool, int, char, string, and etc.

That is optional.  A return value is temporary and goes out of scope at the end of the statement, if it is not assigned to a variable to extend its lifetime.

> However, for ostream and istream, the returned type of ostream& is not being saved.

It does not have to be.  It just has to stay alive long enough for the next operator to be called on it, if the final `;` has not been reached yet.

> Then, in this case, shouldn't it be void (carry out the task and terminate without returning any values)?

No.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau: Thank you for your answer. It is very clear now. I've become too used to saving the returned value, and neglected the fact that it is not mandatory. By the way, could you please explain why the return and input ostream types should be references? Could they be just normal copy? so the prototype would be 'ostream operator << ( ostream output, const PhoneNumber &number ).' I see that use of reference is more efficient in this case, but wonder if it is a 'have to.'

Comment: @GrinNare: If they were not references, every operator call would create a new copy of the stream, and who is to say if a given stream persists state information from one copy to the next. Remember that some of the operators accept manipulators as input to modify the state of the stream. It is not unusual to have many operators and manipulators called on a single stream object. So passing references is not just more efficient, it is preferred so they know they are operating on the original stream and not some Nth copy of it.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau: Thank you again for your reply. For operators such as ++a or --a, I see that passing reference makes much more sense. However,  in this specific case, I do not see any problem in streaming the copy of an object (the same end result) other than the efficiency issue, am I correct? I completely agree on the use of reference in general, but I'm asking simply to confirm my understanding.

Comment: @GrinNare: You are ignoring what I said about stream states and [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). If references were not used, manipulators would be manipulating copies of the stream, not the original stream. It is not uncomon to have multiple manipulators chained together, and then the cumulative effect of all the modifications applied to one streamed value. You lose that ability if copies are used everywhere. State information has to be passed from one operator to another, and that is better performed by passing the stream by reference rather than by value.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau: Hm... I'm not so sure if I'm following 100% because I do not have firm grasp over 'streaming' and 'manipulator.' However, I believe that you are saying 'certain action' on a stream may not be copied as the stream is copied. This may result in unexpected result. Is... this correct? ;(

Comment: @GrinNare: something like that, yes.  Any given state value assigned to one copy of the stream may not be assigned to the next copy. It depends on the particular stream implementation and how it handles copy construction.  Remember that `<<` and `>>` are not just for `cout` and `cin`, but for many kinds of streams (strings, files, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Because otherwise you would be able to chain the calls to `operator<<`. This:

```
cout << phone << endl;
```

is parsed as:

```
(cout << phone) << endl;
```

and resolves as:

```
operator<<(cout, phone).operator<<(endl);
```

So it first calls `operator<<(cout, phone)`, which returns `cout`, which then allows the second `<<` to call `cout.operator<<(endl)`.

If `operator<<` returned e.g. `void`, the second `<<` would try to call `operator<<(void, endl)` which would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why is the friend function returning `ostream&`?"*

To make this part of the call chain working

```
phone << endl;
```

The `ostream&` reference is passed through all of these function calls, and thus the `operator<<()` function can be called again on the result.